# Как сохранить выбранный <option> в <selecet> при обновлении страницы

Tags: php, html

Есть блок фильтрации с помощью `<select>-ов`, при выборе значения `<select>-а` и нажатия на кнопку выполняется запрос, страница обновляется и в таблицу загружаются данные, как сделать что бы при обновлении страницы выбранный `<option>` сохранялся и отображался как `Disabled`

код:

```
   <select name="ovdrb">
          <option selected disabled hidden>Укажите ОВД</option>
          <?php   if (!empty ($resselovdrb)){ foreach ($resselovdrb as $resovd){ ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $resovd->id_ovdrb; ?>"><?php  echo $resovd->name_ovdrb;?></option>
          <?php }?>
          <?php }else{?>
          <option>В БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ НЕТ ЗАПИСЕЙ</option>
          <?php }?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Записываете состояние нужных вам компонентов (раз у вас уже шлется запрос на сервер при нажатии), и при выдаче-отрисовке страницы учитываете это. В чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Как вариант - куки, сессии, добавление параметра фильтра к URL и т.д

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
$ovdrb = $_POST['ovdrb'];

 <select name="ovdrb">
     <option disabled >Все ОВД</option>
      <?php if (!empty ($resselovdrb)){foreach ($resselovdrb as $resovd){?>
       <option  value="<?= $r=$resovd->id_ovdrb ?>"<?= $r==$ovdrb?'selected':'' ?><?= $resovd->name_ovdrb ?></option>
       <?php }}else{?>
       <option>В БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ НЕТ ЗАПИСЕЙ</option>
       <?php }?>
       </select>
    </div>
```